# Date changed broadcast receiver not received when date changed to past date

Tags: android, date, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a broadcast for listening date change event.I am able to receive broadcast when user change date to future date i.e. if today is 23rd September and user change date to 24th September, but when I change the date to already passed date i.e. to 22nd September it is not received in my registered broadcast.Please can any one help me on this.

Comment: what intent filters are you using for your service or broadcastreceiver?

Comment: intentfilters used is android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED

Comment: @JalpaShah Have you solved this?

Comment: @hemanthKumar no still issue persists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following intent actions in addition to what you have used in your app.

1.`Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK`

2.`Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`

3.`Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`

Comment: Still facing the same issue.. :(

Comment: Issue is once the time is taken back.For future dates it is working fine.